# Setting up a 3 monitor display?

Tags: x11, graphics, multi-monitor, xrandr

I currently have a Radeon HD 5750 graphics card and an [M3N78-PRO motherboard](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/AMD_AM2Plus/M3N78_PRO/). I use both outputs of my graphics card for a 2 screen display. I use `xrandr` at boot to set up my two screens.

However, I was wondering if (1) would it be possible to attach a third monitor to the HDMI output on my motherboard and (2) if it is, how I can use `xrandr` to set up the third monitor correctly.

Hardware-wise, I don't know if this is possible (I sure hope so). If it is possible, will there be any confusion at the OS level as to where to send the display (motherboard vs. graphics card)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current version of RandR protocol does not allow to use multiple graphic devices. It is expected to be implemented in RandR 2.0, but there is no estimate time of release (so do not expect it in the next two years). You might want to see (for example) here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RandR

However, it *might* be possible to configure your monitors without RandR, using the deprecated Xinerama extension. Unfortunately I know close to nothing about Xinerama, so I cannot help you any further.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. +1 and accepted -- I'll have to find another way to do this.

Comment: Just to note that the currently accepted answer is actually incorrect. RandR 1.4 supports multiple GPUs.

Comment: Yes, obviously at the time of writing this answer the most recent RandR version was 1.3. I haven't had hands-on experience with 1.4 yet.